# How many days are there in the Papers Please story?

Tags: papers-please

Exactly what it says in the title:
How many days are there in the Papers Please story?

I want to know how much I have left.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 31 official days and then there is a "performance review" on day 32. The game ends after that, but you can continue in endless mode.

Comment: And on performance review day you get the rest of the day off. Glory to Arstotzka.

Comment: For further details, [see here](https://papersplease.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline).